# Add photo in a button

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

```
class Actions implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Get the button that was clicked
        JButton theButton = (JButton) e.getSource();

        // Set it's background color to white
        Color color = theButton.getBackground();

        if(upload.isSelected()){Icon i=new ImageIcon(upload.getText());
        }
        if(start.isSelected()){
            for(int i=0;i<buttonNum;i++){
                Color check=buttons[i].getBackground();
                if(check==Color.green){
                    buttons[i].setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }
            theButton.setBackground(Color.green);}
        else if(end.isSelected()){
            for(int i=0;i<buttonNum;i++){
                Color check=buttons[i].getBackground();
                if(check==Color.red){
                    buttons[i].setBackground(Color.white);
                }
            }
            theButton.setBackground(Color.red);}
        else if (color==Color.black)
        {
            theButton.setBackground(Color.white);}
        else{theButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        }
    }
}
```

This function will create some buttons using a for loop. I want to add a function that after the upload button selected, when I clicked one of the buttons created by for loop, it will put a photo on the button.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what HTML has to do with this. If you want to display an image in a JButton you use the `setIcon(...)` method

Comment: but  setIcon() cannot inside the action(e),so that i can not choose which button to set icon @camickr

Comment: Don't know what you are saying. You use "theButton" variable to set the background color. You can also use that variable to set the icon.

Comment: i make it like this,but it do not work,what is the problem?


`if(buttonUpload.isSelected()) {
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(location[0]);
theButton.setIcon(icon);
 buttonUpload.setSelected(false);'`
@camickr